# how to find element with its name in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to find checkbox with name `checkbox[]`

```
$("#a_tag_id").parent('tr.section_quick_edit').find('input:checkbox[name=checkbox[]]').val();
```

Comment: What does the relevant html look like? Could you post that here? Ideally with a corresponding [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#a_tag_id").parent('tr.section_quick_edit').find("input:checkbox[name='checkbox[]']").val();
```

Notice the extra quotes.

Bob

Comment: +1 From [the API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): *Quotes are mandatory*

Comment: +1 to @rcravens and @lonesomeday for pointing out that quotes are mandatory. I'd never realised that, 'til now. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$("#a_tag_id").parent('tr.section_quick_edit').find('input:checkbox[name=checkbox[]]').attr('name');
```